# My Query Isn't Working, Please Help Me Finding The Error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

this is my query Guys and somwhere i have an error and cannot run my query:

```
SELECT SUBQUERY.user_id AS user_id,

SUBQUERY.username, GROUP_CONCAT(SUBQUERY.role

ORDER BY SUBQUERY.role SEPARATOR ', ') AS roles,

SUBQUERY.firstname,

SUBQUERY.lastname,

SUBQUERY.email,

SUBQUERY.create_time AS 'user creation date',

IF((

SELECT a.action

FROM auditlog a

WHERE a.action = 'Account: DELETE' AND substr(SUBQUERY.username, INSTR(a.user,"(") + 1, INSTR(a.user,")") - INSTR(SUBQUERY.username,"(") - 1) = SUBQUERY.user_id


)IS NOT NULL, "deactivated", IF(SUBQUERY.locked_time IS NULL, "active", "inactive")) AS "status",
lastLogin

-- ,

-- (

-- SELECT MAX(a.time)

-- FROM auditlog a

-- WHERE a.action = 'LOGIN SUCCESSFUL' AND substr(SUBQUERY.username, INSTR(a.user,"(") + 1,
 
INSTR(a.user,")") - INSTR(SUBQUERY.username,"(") - 1) = SUBQUERY.user_id

-- ) AS last_login

FROM

(

SELECT u.id AS user_id,

u.username,

role,

u.firstname,

u.lastname,

u.email,

u.create_time,

u.locked_time

FROM USER u

INNER JOIN

user_has_role uhr ON

u.id = uhr.user_id

INNER JOIN

role r ON

r.id = uhr.role_id

ORDER BY 2

)SUBQUERY

INNER JOIN



(SELECT

max(a.TIME) AS LastLogin,

CAST(SUBSTR(a.user, INSTR(a.user,"(")+1, INSTR(a.user,")") -1- (INSTR(a.user,"("))) AS INT) AS user_id
FROM auditlog a

WHERE a.action = 'LOGIN SUCCESSFUL'

GROUP BY user_id) b

ON b.user_id = SUBQUERY.user_id

GROUP BY SUBQUERY.user_id

ORDER BY SUBQUERY.user_id
```

Comment: Please post full error message

Comment: to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the 
[Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

INSTR(SUBQUERY.username,"(") - 1) brackets don't pair up